# Creating a local SQL database file?

Tags: sql, local

**Please note:**

*I am a game programmer, so backend development isn't my forte. There are times, however, where I work with our database at my job. Please don't shoot me if my question is ridiculous.*

Is there a way to create a local mySQL file and access it through PHP or C#?

I know you can make a local webpage on your machine (pretty much for testing purposes) and access multiple locally created files.

I assume that something similar would work with mySQL. (Are the login credentials also stored within the file?) I remember seeing a few online tutorials where it offered a download for both PHP and the database file, but I can't seem to find them now.

I've searched for this, but all the relevant results involved downloading mySQL and hosting a server which is a bit more than I wanted to do.

So if its possible to create a local mySQL, how do you do so?

The tools I intend on using while doing this:
PHP/JQUERY/HTML and C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MyISAM tables, inside the MySQL data directory there is one directory per database which contains several (usually three) files per table. For InnoDB tables, they are all contained in several files directly inside the data directory.

The location of the MySQL data directory is usually set in *my.cnf* using the `datadir` parameter.

The login credentials are stored in a special database called "mysql" which is in that data directory like any other database.

However, you have to install and run MySQL to access those files. You cannot access them with PHP or any other client API alone. If you want to do such a thing, better use SQLite.

Comment: So SQLite would allow me to create a few database files - the config and file in which the data is stored?

Comment: With SQLite all configuration is done using the client API and all data is stored in one file (plus journal files during writes). Of course you can access multiple SQLite database files from you application. BTW, I forgot to elaborate on MySQL login credentials, I updated the answer.

Comment: That is really cool! so essentially the SQL commands are stored with the application? and this would work for both C# applications and PHP querys?

Comment: Yes, see the example on http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-open.php. In that example `mysqlitedb` is the filename of the database file.

Comment: I don't know how simple but xml may be an option as well.

Comment: XML wouldn't be a very good option for my case. Thank you, though.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is a database engine, u need to install that before you can use it. Unlike SQLite which stores it's database in files. Maybe that is something more of your liking. And I know there are library that supports SQLite for PHP, not sure about the rest.

SQLite you don't need to install anything.

Comment: Would SQLite files still be read from with the mySQL querys? ie: "INSERT" or "UPDATE"?

Comment: SQLite is not part of MYSQL, SQLite is another database type, but the upside to SQLite is that it is in file format, and as long as the platform you coding with has the library to access these files, you don't need to install anything. While MySQL you need to install the database server in order to use it. SQLiter is in SQL format if that is your second question. There are some syntax difference, but it is SQL, just as you would be saying Oracle is SQL.

Comment: That makes much more sense. Thank you for explaining! I think SQLite would be the better solution. I believe was thinking mySQL was the format instead of the middleware for communication to the data.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL can be used an [an embedded database](http://www.mysql.com/oem/), but you will need to contact them in order to purchase a copy of it.

Comment: All I need is a file to push and pull information from with mySQL querys. I think purchasing a database would be much more than what I need. This is a type of "test" for applicants to see if they possess working knowledge of mySQL and using it with web forms and applications.

Comment: You can't *get* the "file to push and pull information from with mySQL querys" unless you purchase it.

Comment: So then mySQL would be a middleware between the database information and application/webpage?

Comment: That's disappointing. I thought the dll contained the code to execute such commands to search through files. So creating a local file to push and pull data from would be better as a text file as opposed to database (on a small scale)?

Comment: The DLL contains code to communicate with the database server. I don't know enough about your application to determine whether a text file or a database would be better.

Comment: I believe I was confusing mySQL with SQL as a format. Thanks for the help!